# Как работать с элементами Web страницы в расширении для google chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, api, html, javascript, css

Пишу расширение для google chrome, которое отображает html элементы выбранной пользователем страницы.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в коде для расширения google chrome получить информацию о дереве HTML элементов выбранной пользователем страницы?

**Обновление**

Это расширение для google chrome. Т.е. пользователь устанавливает моё расширение. В браузере google chrome открывает интересующую его страницу и чёлкает на кнопочку моего расширения в браузере. А расширение, после этого, анализирует код страницы и выводит дерево элементов. Нельзя ли через API google chrome получить дерево элементов этой страницы или можно только получить адрес страницы, а потом действительно через ajax запрос получить HTML?

**Обновление 2**

Страница выбирается в браузере google chrome. Т.е. расширение работает со страницей, которая открыта и активна у пользователя в браузере google chrome. Т.е. в само расширение пользователь не вводит в ручную url, а получает его от браузера. В том и смысл расширения.

Насчёт кода - пока ещё не написал, пока пытаюсь понять, как это вообще сделать. Но из похожих расширений есть SelectorGadget.

Comment: Так а саму страницу вы загружаете или нет? Я так понял, что пользователь вводит url просто, а дльше вам нужны html элементы? Нужно отправить GET запрос с помощью ajax, получите html, дальше можно работать с ним. Соответственно нужно подключить jquery в manifest.

Comment: Непонятно, где выбранные, каким образом выбранные (кликнул, нажал на кнопку), из чего выбран, да и вообще киньте код, который уже у вас имеется.

Comment: Обновил вопрос

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не знаю как сейчас, возможно что-то поменялось в api, но пару лет назад я решал эту задачу так, в манифест прописываешь строки

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": [ "*://*/*" ],
        "js": [ "myscript.js" ],
        "css": [ "mystyle.css" ],
        "run_at": "document_start"
    }
],
```

Таким образом ты внедряешь свой скрипт и свои стили - myscript.js, myscript.css на все страницы которые открывает пользователь, и теперь из этого скрипта тебе доступны все элементы.

Answer (score 0):

api google chrome здесь https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index

Получить все элементы страницы можно через свойства *document* по инъекции на странице.